# adding elements in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing a prolog code and in the middle I want to add 2 variables and store it in one of them
I want to write some like this

```
N is N+R.
```

but it wont accept this can anyone tell me why and whats is the correct syntax
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no correct syntax. N can't be equal to N+R (unless R is 0, in which case N will be N+R no matter what the value of N is). You can't update the value of a variable to something new the way you intend to. Prolog doesn't work like that.

Prolog doesn't have the concept of a variable having one value at one point in time and then having another value after a given statement executes. All you can ever do to a variable is restrict its possible values.

Obviously I don't know the big picture of what you're trying to do here, but perhaps you can achieve what you want by calling your predicate recursively with `NPR` being the new value for N (where `NPR is N + R`).

Comment: good answer, but you miss the simplest suggestion, that the OP was seeking: **N1 is N+R**,...